# Playing HTML5 audio from mobile devices from callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, audio, mobile

I want to be able to play an audio file from a callback function using javascript and HTML5 elements. From what I've read, the only way that most mobile devices play HTML5 audio is via user interaction (i.e. button click etc).

My scenario is slightly different. The button click event makes an ajax call with a callback function, and based on the results returned, a different sound is supposed to be played. This works fine on desktop browsers, however both android and the iPad do not seem to support this.

Does anyone know of any workarounds?

Sample code showing how audio objects are initialised etc:

```
    var sound = new Audio('Sample.wav');
    var sound2 = new Audio('Sample2.wav');

/// Button events etc here, stock standard stuff

    function MyCallBack(e)
    {
      if(e.someValue)
       sound.play();
      else
       sound2.play();
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I've solved this problem using a similar solution as outlined below. On the user event I played then immediately paused the sounds. Once the callback returned, I resumed playing the appropriate sound

```
 hit.play(); hit.pause(); fail.play(); fail.pause();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try placing both sounds into a single audio file, and then using the callback to queue up and play at the correct location.

Going this route, you can start playing the sound on the initial user click (with empty space at the beginning) and then immediately pause it (from the play event to ensure it began playing). Once the callback comes in, set the currentTime to the place on the audio track you want to play and begin playing. Playing this way should work, because the *initial* play call occurred on a user action.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good idea. The main reason that `play` is restricted in mobile devices is to prevent unwanted *loading* of files that eat up your data quota. If you can have a `play` triggered by a user action once, as long as you don't change the source, you can procedurally re-`play` it freely afterwards.

Comment: Hi, I'm awarding this as the answer as I had solved this doing something similar. On the user event, i played and immediately paused the different sounds that might play, and on the return of the callback I resumed the appropriate sound

Answer (score 1):

To extend on Derek's answer, here's the jQuery code to make this happen for a given `audio` element:

```
<audio preload="auto" id="yourHTMLaudio">
    <source src="/sounds/youraudio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="/sounds/youraudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="/sounds/youraudio.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

On the button's `click` event, call the following:

```
$("#yourbutton").on("click", function() {
    ...
    $("#yourHTMLaudio").trigger('play').trigger('pause').prop("currentTime", 0);
    ...
```

Then in your Ajax `done()` function you can just play it like you normally would:

```
    ...
    $.ajax({
        ...
    }).done(function(msg) {
        ...
        $("#yourHTMLaudio").trigger('play');
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 audio tag is supported in almost all of the smart phone browsers these days

Try

```
    <audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">  
       <source src="music.ogg" />  
       <source src="music.mp3" />  
    </audio>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is about how I can get around the restriction requiring some form of user input before playing the sound. In my case, the user clicks a button which performs an ajax request, and based on that request, plays a different sound. Currently, it does not seem possible and was wondering if someone has solved that issue